# yaml expected mapping

Tags: networking, netplan

I am setting up my static ip but i keep getting the error:
Error in network defenition etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 0 collumn 8: expected mapping.

Here is my config:

```
 network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
 ens3:
 dhcp4: no
 dhcp6: no
 addresses: [5.157.82.219/23]
 gateway4: 5.157.82.1
 nameservers:
 addresses: [109.235.76.162,93.94.226.236,85.158.203.252,85.158.200.76,8.8.8.8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent the properties accordingly to identify parent and child properties. Otherwise `netplan` is not able to parse your YAML configuration. A valid YAML file for netplan would be as follows.

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  ens3:
   dhcp4: no
   dhcp6: no
   addresses: [5.157.82.219/23]
   gateway4: 5.157.82.1
   nameservers:
    addresses: [109.235.76.162,93.94.226.236,85.158.203.252,85.158.200.76,8.8.8.8]
```

You are free in choosing the indentation spaces, but it should be the same within the YAML file.

For comprehensive examples of netplan configurations, please also read through [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, its working.

Now i want to add a second ip, my vps has 2 ip-adresses

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  ens3:
   dhcp4: no
   dhcp6: no
   addresses: [5.157.82.219/23, 185.37.68.40/24]
   gateway4: 5.157.82.1
   nameservers:
    addresses: [109.235.76.162,93.94.226.236,85.158.203.252,85.158.200.76,8.8.8.8]
```

But it's not working.. can not ping the second ip. in ifconfig the ip does not show up.

I think the config is correct?